# How can I force running a php extension after each php call without explicitly writing the code?

Tags: php, wordpress, hhvm

Let's say I host 1000 wordpress websites, instead of installing a plugin that

```
      echo "site designed by john doe"; 
      // also echo google analytics <script>
```

Is it possible to have a php extension that does that without needing me to install a plugin and activating it all the time? I don't mind if the script echos after  closing tag

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to `php.ini`, you can use [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) or [`auto_append_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) to cause code to be executed before/after the main file.

Comment: @JohnDoe was this of any help?

Comment: what if i wanted the function to be called in the middle of runtime?

e.g. as a plugin function?

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm not familiar enough with wordpress to know if that's possible. I'll delete this answer, that may help you get other ones which can help.